# SortedDictionary ArgumentException: "Æ" and "AE" considered the same keys

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, unique, sorteddictionary

I was trying to use SortedDictionary to store some of my data from file, but got really weird bunch of key duplication exceptions. I came up with the next code sample which reproduces my issue:

```
var dict = new SortedDictionary<string, string>();
dict.Add("Æ", "qwerty"); // "aesc" (aka "ash"), single symbol
Console.WriteLine(dict["AE"]); // outputs "qwerty" for two-symbol string "AE"
dict.Add("AE", ""); // ArgumentException: An entry with the same key already exists.
```

[This code on .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/t0BU9e)

It's not happening for usual Dictionary though and I finally decided to use it instead. But I still wonder why is it a problem for a sorted one? Unfortunatelly, I was unable to google an answer myself (got a lot of AES-related noise) and can't debug into SortedDictionary's code despite MS recently made some of .NET source code open.

It's almost seems like this class implicitly runs some string preprocessing/normalization function, but I just can't believe it is an actual reason.

Any ideas why is it happening? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's because `string.Compare("Æ", "AE") == 0`. Check out the remarks [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b7zs7dcf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because of the culture.  Try `new SortedDictionary(StringComparer.Ordinal)`, for example.

The reason Dictionary behaves differently is that it uses `EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default` while SortedDictionary uses `Comparer<TKey>.Default`.

Comment: And `Comparer<string>.Default` ends up using `String.Compare()`

Comment: @MatthewWatson actually it uses the `IComparable<string>` implementation, which calls `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.CompareInfo.Compare(string, string, CompareOptions)`, passing zero for the options.  See http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,2114.  Furthermore, the default equality comparer uses the `IEquatable<string>` implementation, which does an ordinal comparison.

Comment: @MatthewWatson of course, `String.Compare(string, string)` *also* calls `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.CompareInfo.Compare(string, string, CompareOptions)`, so it's just as good as if what you said were true.  See http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,1756.

Comment: That's really what I wanted to express: It ends up doing exactly the same as what `string.Compare()` does.

Comment: Many thanks. Any idea why Ordinal is not a default behaviour?

Comment: @SimpleV presumably because most users want to have language-appropriate sorting by default.  For example, "apple" should come before "Berries," but the ordinal comparison would put "Berries" before "apple."